# Powershell SQL Server query is creating duplicate entries

Tags: powershell

I have a ps1 script created to run a query on a SQL Server database. After that I run the rows in a for loop however, the dataset is duplicating entries. If I run the query directly on MS SQL without the script, it does not duplicate rows.

```
$SQLServer = "bla";
$SQLDBName = "bla";
$uid ="bla";
$pwd = "HIdden_Password";

$App="com.android.app";

$SqlQuery = "SELECT value
FROM obj_user u
 JOIN obj_user_device d ON d.id_user = u.id_user
 JOIN obj_device od ON od.id_device = d.id_device
 JOIN def_device_hardware dh ON dh.id_device_hardware = od.id_device_hardware
 JOIN def_device_os do ON do.id_device_os = od.id_device_os
 JOIN obj_user_device_app_state das ON das.id_user_device = d.id_user_device
 LEFT JOIN obj_device_setting ods ON ods.id_device = od.id_device
 LEFT JOIN obj_user_setting ous ON ous.id_user = d.id_user
 AND das.bundle_id = '$App'";

Write("Number of results from query:") 

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$DataSet.Tables[0]

foreach ($row in $Dataset.tables[0].rows)
{
   Write ("entry $row.value")
}
```

You can see that the `$rowcCount` shows value of 2 but when I print it it shows 4 entries when it should be 2.

Number of results from query: 2

```
value                
-----                
**3a5b220714243811**
105986685869347611614
3a5b220714243811
**105986685869347611614**
```

The forloop also prints 4 entries

```
 Write ("entry $row.value")

entry 3a5b220714243811
**entry 105986685869347611614**
**entry 3a5b220714243811**
entry 105986685869347611614
```

Same with out-file from $dataset. NOte: the headings for the SQL columns are not duplicated just the results

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] | out-file "File.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. these two are causing the dups removing one works fine

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```